# AWS Sync S3 with EC2 Clarification Question

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

If I sync an s3 bucket to an EC2 instance, when a new file is added to s3 does it automatically add it to my EC2 instance, or is it only the other way around (EC2 file --> add to s3 bucket).

I need to have any new files added to my s3 bucket to be added to my EC2 instance, so s3 bucket --> EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a sync is a one-time operation. You would need to run it again each time files change wether your are copying them to or from s3.

Depending on your OS on the EC2 instances, there are ways to 'mount' an s3 bucket as a folder on an ec2 instance.

Googling 'mount s3 bucket to ec2' will get you started if that is what you want to do.